# Recognize the kind of retrieve-record-object in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am building a `crud-route-mixin` where I define default functions and  actions for routes.

One of the functions has as argument a query object; within the action I perform the call:

```
_doSomething(query) {
    query.then( result => {
        //do something default with this result
    })
}
```

The routes call the `_doSomething` function with different [kind of methods](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/finding-records/). For example:

*Route A*

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(CrudRoute, {
    setupController() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this._doSomething(this.get('store').findAll('paper'));
    }      
}
```

*Route B*

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(CrudRoute, {
    setupController() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        this._doSomething(this.get('store').findRecord('blog-post'));
    }      
}
```

I was wondering, is it possible to retrieve the method name or type of the query object? So I could do something like this (pseudo code):

```
_doSomething(query) {
    query.then( result => {
        if (query.getRetrieveMethodName() === 'findAll') {
            //do something default with this array result
        } else if (query.getRetrieveMethodName() === 'findRecord') {
            //do something default with this single record result
        }
    })
}
```

P.S. Check if the payload is a single record or array is not an option, because I need this distiction in the error handling as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query object returned from `findRecord` or `findAll` or `query` is either `PromiseObject` or `PromiseArray` (if you use ember-data). So you can check it type like this (even in case of error):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

_doSomething(query) {
    if (query instanceof DS.PromiseObject) {
       // single result
    }
    else if (query instanceof DS.PromiseArray) {
       // array 
    }
    else {
       throw new Error('Expected ember-data proxy object');
    }
    // Do something useful
 }
```

But would not it be more simple to provide required data to the controller?

```
_doSomething(query, modelName, isArray) {
   query.then( result => {
      //do something default with this result
   });
}

export default Ember.Route.extend(CrudRoute, {
   setupController() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      this._doSomething(this.get('store').findRecord('blog-post'), 'blog-post', false);
   }
```

}

Comment: `But would not it be more simple to provide required data to the controller?`. Yes, but this question is a simplified version of my current situation. Using `instanceof` [object] does provide the needed solution, so many thanks!